# How to remove Category URL from Wordpress Polylang

Tags: wordpress, polylang

**How to remove category URL WordPress Polylang**

I have removed category URL by setting Search Appearance > Taxonomy Category remove in Yoast SEO and also have a correct setup in the WordPress settings permalink.
However Polylang doesn't seems to consider any of those. It adds Sub-Category URL to the link which leads to broken links.

Any idea how to resolve this? Thank you.